# Substitution to leave only non-matching characters on a line

Tags: regex, vim, sublimetext2

I'm trying to get an accurate list of all of the tube stations in London with their corresponding lines. I'm taking this information from Wikipedia, where I've copied the article source text and am using regex search and replace to just leave the name of the tube station and the name of its lines on each line of the file.

I've already managed to separate out the tube station names onto their own lines. So now I've been trying to find a regular expression that will match only characters that aren't the names of London underground lines within a line of the file and remove these. Then it'll be easier to filter out.

I've tried various methods in Vim and Sublime Text but I'm not really sure what would work.

```
(?!Bakerloo|Central|District|Hammersmith & City|Jubilee|Metropolitan|Northern|Piccadilly|Victoria|Waterloo & City).*
```

The above matches far too greedily. Any help?

Edit: I've reduced the file down to just the lines containing the line names. A line of the file looks like this:

```
| [[File:ActonTown1.jpg|100px|alt=A brown-bricked building with a flat-slabbed roof and six columns of windows on the front face standing below a blue sky with white clouds|Acton Town]] || [[District line|District]]<br>[[Piccadilly line|Piccadilly]] || [[London Borough of Ealing|Ealing]] || {{ctr|[[Travelcard Zone 3|3]]}} || {{ctr|{{dts|format=dmy|1879|July|1}}}} || {{sort|z|}} || Mill Hill Park: 1879–1910 || {{ctr|{{nts|5.75}}}}
```

Comment: can you add an example text also. ?

Comment: okay so your regex matches the text you provided. what is the problem with it ?. Sorry for my misunderstanding but can you add a little more clarification

Comment: I want to leave only the name of the tube lines on each line

Comment: then why not simply use : `Bakerloo|Central|District|Hammersmith & City|Jubilee|Metropolitan|Northern|Piccadilly|Victoria|Waterloo & City`

Comment: I ended up having to use that regex and then invert the selection

Comment: I ask myself several times how to invert a selection with regex... Impossible to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides a `:DeleteExcept` command that might help you (if I understand your requirements correctly):

```
:%DeleteExcept /Bakerloo\|Central\|District\|Hammersmith & City\|Jubilee\|Metropolitan\|Northern\|Piccadilly\|Victoria\|Waterloo & City/
```